# autowired ObjectMapper is null during @DataJpaTest

Tags: junit, spring-data-jpa, objectmapper

I want to test my implementation for `AttributeConverter` using `@DataJpaTest`.

**test code**

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
class FooRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private FooRepository repository;

    @Test
    void getPojoTest(){
        FooEntity fooEnity= repository.findById("foo");
        FooPojo fooPojo = fooEntity.getJsonPojo()
        //some assertion
        

    }
}
```

**Entity**

```java
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class FooEntity{

    ....

    @Column(columnDefinition= "JSON")
    @Convert(converter = FooConverter.class)
    private FooPojo data;

    ....
}
```

**Attribute Converter**

```java
public class FooConverter implements AttributeConverter<FooPojo, String> {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(FooPojo attribute) {
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(attribute);
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public FooPojo convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return mapper.readValue(dbData, FooPojo.class);
    }
}
```

with my code above, when I run `getPojoTest()`,  the `@autowired` `OjbectMapper` in Converter is `null`. When I try the same test with `@SpringBootTest` instead, it works just fine. I wonder is there any walk-around to use `@DataJpaTest` and `ObjectMapper` together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better alternative compared to creating your own `ObjectMapper` is adding the `@AutoConfigureJson` annotation:

```
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@AutoConfigureJson
public void FooRepositoryTest {

}
```

This is also what [@JsonTest](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/json/JsonTest.java) uses.

Answer (score 1):

From [Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html):

> @DataJpaTest can be used if you want to test JPA applications. By
> default it will configure an in-memory embedded database, scan for
> @Entity classes and configure Spring Data JPA repositories. Regular
> @Component beans will not be loaded into the ApplicationContext.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand that, as the doc said, the objectMapper bean is not created by Spring Context while using `@DataJpaTest`. so i am now using `new ObjectMapper()` for the same test, and it works just fine.